# Why doesn't Reduce work?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I try to solve an inequality with parameters using Reduce.
The answer i get is  :

This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Here is the inequality:

````
Reduce[(-(1/lamda)*
      Log[(delta - beta*(1 - 2 d))/(lamda*delta)])^(rho - 1) > 
   0 && (delta - beta*(1 - 2 d)) > 0 && 
  (delta - beta*(1 - 2 d))/(lamda*delta)< 1 && delta > 0 && 
  0 < lamda < 1 && rho < 1 && 0 < d < 1/2, beta]


```
````

Comment: This is a system of inequalities,  including a transcendental inequality, with many parameters. Every command has its limitations.

Comment: okay thanks, what command should I use then?

Comment: Restrict the domain to `Reals`, i.e., `Reduce[(-(1/lamda)* Log[(delta - beta*(1 - 2 d))/(lamda*delta)])^(rho - 1) > 0 && (delta - beta*(1 - 2 d)) > 0 && (delta - beta*(1 - 2 d))/(lamda*delta) < 1 && delta > 0 && 0 < lamda < 1 && rho < 1 && 0 < d < 1/2, beta, Reals]`